# Hide button when click, start timer, download automatically when countdown finished

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding. I am using image as my button. I want to hide the button when click and timer to start. When timer finish, i want a link to open automatically. (One more issue I've described at the end)

here is HTML and JAVASCRIPT that i'm using right now

```
<div id="download_button">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cel0yjs0H4A/X1tGU7oDpyI/AAAAAAAAATk/zw9Qa7YUnT4KOe8exOaxx-LJlFFofhjMACLcBGAsYHQ/s150/pdf-download-link.png" /></a>
    </div>
<center>
  <b>
    <span style="font-size: 30px;">
      <span id="countdown"></span>
    </span>
  </b>
</center>
```

and JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="application/javascript">
document.getElementById("download_button").addEventListener("click", function(){
var timeleft = 5;

var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1(){
document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Please wait "+ timeleft + " seconds";

timeleft -= 1;
if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "downloading..."
}
 }, 1000);

   console.log(countdown);
});
```

And there is one more issue that i want to fix.
When 2 seconds left, "downloading..." appears. I want it to be appear when 1 second left instead of 2 seconds.

Thank you

Comment: Could  you give a bit more information on what you want to happen when the user clicks on the image please? At the moment a click takes you straight to google.com rather than the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a small hint, please describe what does and what doesn't work with your attempt.
Anyway, your countdown probably doesn't work, so let's look into that.

The first issue is that upon clicking the link, your browser immediately follows it, but you want a countdown. We thus have to prevent this from happening. The [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method of `Event` might help you with that.
Your event listener would then start out like this:

```js
document.getElementById("download_button").addEventListener("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault()
```

Now we need to hide the image. This can be done by setting it's `display` property to `none`, which might look like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#download_button a img').style.display = "none";
```

After the countdown finishes, you need a way to actually trigger the download.
We could simulate a click by using the below code, but that would just create an infinite loop...

```js
document.querySelector('#download_button a').click();
```

It is in fact much easier to directly trigger a navigate from JS:

```js
window.location.href = document.querySelector('#download_button a').href;
```

Here we used [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the right element and edit it. It's very versatile, but if your button moves, you might have to change the selector. Using an id would be more stable.

Now, your last problem is that the *downloading...* phase is triggered too soon.
This is a typical problem of ordering statements. In your code, you decrease the value of `timeleft` before checking if it's 0. If you put that line all the way at the end, your problem will be solved.

I made [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Epse/pnsodgcy/) to show you how these things might work together.

Finally, I would like to remark that using things like `<center>` and `<b>` is discouraged (it should be done in CSS). Best of luck with your further learning!

Comment: Hey @Epse ! Thank you so much. It works. Thanks alot. You're a gem ❤️ You solved all my issues. ❤️

Comment: You're welcome @AsifRiaz! Please do mark my answer as the solution if it worked :)

Comment: Done 
@Epse can you do me a one more favor?
If i want that downloading link to open in a new tab when countdown finished, what should i do? <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"> is not working for me.

Comment: You could replace the line with `window.location.href` with `window.open(document.querySelector('#download_button a).href, '_blank);` but it might get blocked by the popup blocker

Comment: No
It open up the link in new tab but direct. Without timer.

Comment: I made [another Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Epse/pmunvh8j/)

Comment: Hey @Epse! Thanks alot
window.open(document.querySelector('#download_button a').href, '_blank');
This works ❤️ Just placed ' after #download_button a and _blank and it works perfectly.
Thank you so muchhhhh bro ❤️ #LotsOfLove

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas.

1. There is a delay starting the countdown. Solution: Add a countdown message above the setInterval
2. To fix the DL starting too early, move the timeleft - 1 above the next message
3. To prevent the a tag default behavior, add e.preventDefault() (which requires that you pass the e into the function)
4. Handy trick: use $ to replace all the document.getElementBy queries (note: this is not jQuery!)

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
var timeleft = 5;
$("#download_button").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default a navigation behavior
    $("#download_button").style.display = 'none';
    $("#countdown").innerHTML = "Please wait "+ timeleft + " seconds"; //for quick start
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1(){
        timeleft -= 1; //moved this line up 1 to fix timing
        $("#countdown").innerHTML = "Please wait "+ timeleft + " seconds";
        if(timeleft <= 0){
            clearInterval(downloadTimer);
            $("#countdown").innerHTML = "downloading...";
            let dlRef = $("#download_button a").href;
            window.location.href = dlRef;
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<style>
    #countdown{font-size:30px;}
</style>

<div id="download_button">
    <a href="https://www.google.com"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cel0yjs0H4A/X1tGU7oDpyI/AAAAAAAAATk/zw9Qa7YUnT4KOe8exOaxx-LJlFFofhjMACLcBGAsYHQ/s150/pdf-download-link.png" /></a>
</div>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Also, try not to inline your styles. Inline styles look like this:

```
<span style="color:red">This is red</span>
```

Either use a style tag, or an external file for your styles:

```
<span class="fgRed">This is red</span>
<style>
    .fgRed{color: red;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you @cssyphus ❤️